# SQL query for ignore duplicate data using MySQL

Tags: mysql

I need one help.I need to fetch some data from one table but one column value should not duplicate.I am explaining my query below.

```
select  Product_name,pro_Id from db_product_info order by Product_name
```

Here I need the duplicate value of product name should not fetch.Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this case, You can use `group by`

```
SELECT  
    Product_name,
    pro_Id 
FROM 
    db_product_info 
GROUP BY Product_name 
ORDER BY Product_name ASC
```

See [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0b730/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 select  Product_name,pro_Id from db_product_info group by product_name order by Product_name
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic way of removing duplicates is to use DISTINCT:

```
select distinct Product_name,pro_Id 
from db_product_info 
order by Product_name
```

If you data has Product_name's with different pro_Id's, you need to decide which pro_Id to choose from. In this case you need to use aggregate function (min, max) combibed with GROUP BY:

```
select Product_name, max(pro_Id)
from db_product_info 
group by Product_name
order by Product_name
```